# jsf access element from array in properties file

Tags: arrays, jsf, el, properties-file

How do I access an element from an array in a properties file?

```
testKey = word1,word2,word3
```

Something like this is not working (assume properties file is mapped to "msg"

```
#{msg.testKey[0]} <- to access first element
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a `String`, not a `String[]`. You've got to split it on the comma first by [`fn:split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/fn/split.fn.html) to get a `String[]` out of it so that you can access the items by an index.

```
#{fn:split(msg.testKey, ',')[0]}
```

Comment: I hoped for something like the Java provided function: "String[] java.util.ResourceBundle.getStringArray(String key)"

Comment: That's unfortunately not possible. It only applies to in-memory properties.